# Optimize query?

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

My query took 28.39 seconds to run. How can I optimize it?

```
explain SELECT distinct UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)*1000 as timestamp,count(a.sig_name) as counter from event a,network n  where n.fsi='pays' and n.net=inet_ntoa(a.ip_src) group by date(timestamp) order by timestamp asc;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--- ---+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 8177074 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fsi   | PRIMARY | 77      | func |       1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: You should post your query plan, but at first glance, your join seems like it would be quite intensive.  `n.fsi='pays' and n.net=inet_ntoa(a.ip_src)`.  Both comparing to a string and  having to run a function on each row will likely be the bulk of your processing time.

Answer (score 3):

So generally looking at your query, we find that table `event` `a` is examining 8,177,074 rows.  That is likely the "root" of the slowness, so we want to look at how to reduce the search space using indexes.

The main condition on `event` `a` is

```
n.net=inet_ntoa(a.ip_src)
```

The problem here is that we need to perform a calculation (inet_ntoa) on every row of a.ip_src, so there is no alternative but to scan the entire table.  A potentially better solution would be to invert the comparison and ensure that a.ip_src is indexed.

```
a.ip_src=inet_aton(n.net)
```

This will only be better if we are matching less rows in `n` than we are in `a`.  If that is not the case, you should seriously consider caching the result of this function in the table and creating an index on that.

Lastly I am guessing the timestamp column is in `event` `a`, in which case an index will potentially help with ordering and grouping though may not.  You could try a multi_column index on (ip_src,timestamp)

Comment: Thank You Very Very Very Much ... everything i'ts ok now

Answer (score 1):

Make it a practice to introduce at-least index on columns which can be used in `WHERE/JOIN` clauses. I've used the at-least because in many cases one should try to use `PRIMARY/FOREIGN KEY` relations. So if something is already a primary/foriegn key there is no need to index it further.

The above query can be simply improved by introducing the INDEX through the following query:

`ALTER TABLE events ADD INDEX idx_ev_ipsrc (ip_src);`

Here `idx_ev_ipsrc` = Name of the index key, and `ip_src` is the column to be indexed.

Even further enhancement:

Introduce multi-colum index on network table using following query:

`ALTER TABLE network ADD INDEX idx_net_fsi_net (fsi,net);`

The above will result in even low number of rows.

Note: The above queries are for MySql and can be tailored for other DBs easily.